# is it possible to include files in the python coverage report that weren't touched at all

Tags: python, python-3.x, coverage.py

I would like my python coverage report to include files that don't get imported by the tests at all.

so if I have a directory with 3 files in it: test.py module1.py module2.py

and both modules have `print(__file__)` in them, and test.py has `import module1` in it

and then I run the test like this:

```
$ python3 -m venv venv
$ venv/bin/pip install coverage
$ venv/bin/coverage run test.py
......../module1.py
$ venv/bin/coverage report
Name         Stmts   Miss  Cover
--------------------------------
module1.py       1      0   100%
test.py          1      0   100%
--------------------------------
TOTAL            2      0   100%
```

but what would be really useful is to be reminded that I have completely forgotten about a file, see `module2.py` on the list with 0% next to it.

Is that possible?  Even when I include that file explicitly, it's not in the report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/6.0.2/source.html

> You can specify source to measure with the --source command-line switch, or the [run] source configuration value. The value is a comma- or newline-separated list of directories or importable names (packages or modules).

> Specifying the source option also enables coverage.py to report on unexecuted files, since it can search the source tree for files that haven’t been measured at all.

Using the same files:

```
$ coverage run  test.py 
............../module1.py
$ coverage report
Name         Stmts   Miss  Cover
--------------------------------
module1.py       1      0   100%
test.py          1      0   100%
--------------------------------
TOTAL            2      0   100%
$ coverage run --source . test.py 
.............../module1.py
$ coverage report
Name         Stmts   Miss  Cover
--------------------------------
module1.py       1      0   100%
module2.py       1      1     0%
test.py          1      0   100%
--------------------------------
TOTAL            3      1    67%
```

The second run includes all files in the current directory `.`.

Comment: Thanks.  Example program works now.  Some of the causes seem to be from my project's particular set-up, and it seems it might be a little easier to solve with version 6 than 5.. My real project was on an old version, and my sample program was using the system `coverage` by accident, which I guess was version 5 (edited now)